# Showing that a matrix of exponential form has determinant 1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, representation-theory

Let $\vec{\sigma}$ be Pauli matrices. Then it is said that $exp(i\vec{\theta} \cdot \vec{\sigma}/2)$ is a matrix belonging the $SU(2)$. Here $\vec{\theta}$ seems lke arbitary vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$/ And However it is unclear to me that the determinant of $exp(i\vec{\theta} \cdot \vec{\sigma}/2)$ is indeed $1$. Could anyone explain why it is $1$? Also something related to this $\vec{\sigma}/2$ is called $SU(2)$ symmetry. What exactly is $SU(2)$ symmetry?

Comment: Something has $SU(2)$ symmetry if $SU(2)$ is (or is at least contained in) its symmetry group.

Answer (score 0):

It is because, for every square matrix $M$, $\det e^M=e^{\operatorname{tr}M}$. Besides, the trace of the Pauli matrices is $0$.

Comment: How can I prove the identity? Also could you tell me what it means by SU (2) symmetry?

Comment: It is a [standard fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#The_determinant_of_the_matrix_exponential). You can prove it, for instance, usinge the fact tat any square matrix is similar to an upper triangular matrix; the equality is very easy to prove for such matrices. I don't know what it means by $SU(2)$ symmetry.